What is the complement of a topological disk within a sphere?
Let $S \subseteq \mathbb R^{n+1}$ be a sphere of dimension $n$.
Suppose that $D \subseteq S$ is homeomorphic to a closed disk of dimension $n$.
What can we say about the complement $C = S \setminus D$?
I suspect that it is always homeomorphic to an open disk of dimension $n$. Moreover, $S$ is obtained from gluing the two disks $D$ and $\overline C$ along the common boundary $\partial D$, which is a sphere of dimension $n-1$.
Is that true, or is there a pathological counterexample?

This is only true when $n\le 2$; google "wild sphere" to understand why.

Thank you. I will need to explore more structure for what I want.

By the way, if you work with diffeomorphisms/smooth embeddings (or homeomorphisms and locally flat embeddings) then your conjecture holds.

Do you happen to know the case of the Lipschitz category?

I think it is the same story as in the topological category. But I am not sure the details were worked out by anybody. There are several detailed examples in the quasisymmetric  category (the first one due to Gehring).
